# SQL ERRO 1442. O que pode ser?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

O erro aparece quando tento inserir algo no banco 3, pois a trigger será ativada e irá inserir no banco2, mas nao estou realizando 2 acoes na mesma tabela como o erro informa...

```
INSERT INTO banco3.Clientes VALUES (6,'RoseMel', '1998-05-08', '48381856' '4539-6', 'ananana', 'oqe?', '162', 'sasnaush', 'qsjqijqiwj',
                                    'SP', '13720000');
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER insereBanco3 AFTER INSERT
ON banco3.clientes FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
        INSERT INTO banco2.cli(id, nome, dat_nascimento, cpf, rg, endereco, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, cep)
        VALUES(NEW.id, NEW.nome, NEW.dat_nascimento, NEW.cpf, NEW.rg, NEW.endereco, NEW.numero, NEW.bairro, NEW.cidade, NEW.estado, NEW.cep); 
END;

$$
```

Comment: Veja se não tem um `trigger` em `banco2.cli`. Fiz um teste bem simples usando seu código e não apresentou erro https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gDkRvHph7afaNouggBeRDE/0

Comment: eu integro 3 bancos na realidade (o banco 2 serve como intermediario pro banco 1 nao acessar o banco 3 e vice e versa). O problema acontece quando começo a usar o terceiro banco. Quando uso só 2, fica tudo bem. Eu li a documentação do mysql e aparentemente ele nao permite que haja duas ações na mesma tabela (ja que tanto o banco 1 quanto o banco 3 inserem na mesma tabela do banco 2). Preciso confirmar para saber se tento corrigir essa falha ou se troco de servidor sql. Sou muito inexperiente pra tomar essa decisão haha